# Electric and magnetic fields with synchrotrons

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Can anyone describe to me one change to the electric field and one change to the magnetic field that MUST take place as particles gains energy in a synchrotron accelerator? This could also just be an in general question about particles gaining energy.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Can you give the context in which you are asking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Synchrotron is a type of accelerator in which the particle stays on a trajectory with a constant radius.

In order to maintain the particle on a circular trajectory, you need to constantly increase the amplitude (the strength) of the magnetic field as the particle gains energy. A machine with a constant magnetic field (and therefore accelerated particle spiraling inside) is called a cyclotron.

As the particle gains energy, its rotation frequency increases. Therefore in order to keep accelerating it, you'll need to ajust the frequency of the eletric field.